# update android application using jquery

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am building an Android application using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap. I would like to update  my data every two months. What is the procedure for doing updates?

My page code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1413" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Admission Status</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a">
                <h3>Bio-medical Engineering</h3>
                <p>
                    <table align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Intake</td>
                            <td>Admitted</td>
                            <td>Vacant</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Little vague, what do the contents consist of where/how is it populated. more info needed to accurately answer.

Comment: this is a college app basically. It consists of college timetables and syllabus  basically which are represented in a list view format.

Comment: updates on this content will be done every 2 months at max

Comment: where does the data reside though? is it in xml, a database of some sort, sqlite. How do you populate the data to begin with, please show a sample of that if u would.

Comment: actually i havent created any database .
i simply wrote this code
<div data-role="page" id="page1413" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Admission Status</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" >
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"  data-theme="a"  >
        <h3>Bio-medical Engineering</h3>
        <p>

Comment: <table align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td>Intake</td>
            <td>Admitted</td>
            <td>Vacant</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </p>
      </div>
what i want is on the day of addmision i would be able to fill the remaing seats available at the end of that day

Comment: I have build my application using html and jquery mobile and then used phonegap build to produce the apk file.  now what i want to know is that if i want to update  any information that is written in my html part and reflect it in my already published app , how can i do it??

Comment: Store the actual data in a Javascript object in the app, and in a database on a server somewhere. Then use AJAX calls to check for updated data when the app loads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the current date in a database on a server or local storage (HTML5 localStorage?) then every time the app starts up, check the current date against the stored date and if enough time has passed, perform the update.

To update data in a web app you need to use AJAX. Try jQuery's `$.ajax` which can grab data from an external source. Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: thanks a lot. there is one more thing that i would like to know.
If i made my app available in google play store. then after that if i made some changes in my app and build a new apk file for it. then if i upload this apk file then will the user be getting automatic updates or not?

Comment: I have no experience with Google Play or Android apps, only jQuery/HTML and limited PhoneGap experience.

Comment: kzz thanks . Do you know how to sign in  a application with a key in phonegap.
And i have no idea for database on a server or local storage (HTML5 local Storage) or sqllite in jquery and html can u provide me some references from where i can learn that?

Comment: I would ask that as a new question.